# Как читать символы кириллицы в json в vscode?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, кириллица

В VSCode пытаюсь редактировать json, и хочется делать это не через dump словаря, а в отдельном окне. Но при попытке открыть файл в новом окне вместо кириллицы высвечивается много символов �, очевидно встающих на место русских букв. Если что, я сохраняю словарь из питоновского файла как dump('словарь',file,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False), но не смотря на последний параметр, русский не высвечивается. При выводе в консоль декодируется нормально, кодировка utf-8. Пытался менять настройки и скачивать расширения, но что-то ничего не помогает.[image: Скрин словаря из .py][image: Скрин файла .json]

Comment: Попробуй всё же нажать на надпись UTF-8 внизу окна VSCode и выбрать кодировку windows1251 она же cp1251. Скорее всего дело в кодировках. Лучше явно указывай кодировку при чтении и записи файлов в своих программах.

Answer (score 2):

Решение оказалось несложным. При открытии файла нужно в `open()` вписывать параметр `encoding='utf8`'. И при записи и при чтении. И не забывать `ensure_ascii=False`.

Comment: Ну да, в винде питон по дефолту пишет файлы в `cp1251` видимо.